# initialise backgroundWoker in code

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

```
TextBox tb = Form1.thisForm.Controls["textbox1"] as TextBox;
```

how come i cant do the same with a backgroundWorker control?

```
backgroundWorker wk = Form1.thisForm.Controls["backgroundWorker1"] as backgroundWorker;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because BackgroundWorker is not Control and doesn't belong to Controls collection.

Windows Form designer generates C# code which creates backgroundWorker1 instance. You can use it directly. But this instance is not added (and cannot be added) to the Form Controls property.

Comment: so do you know of a way to call RunWorkerAsync() on a backgroundWorker which is on form1 from form2.

Comment: That's an entirely different question.

Comment: Well, you changed the title, maybe you can give more details, what exactly you ask.